# How to use SignalR on multiple servers?

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, docker-swarm

I have a chat app that I made with dotnet core, singalR, and react native. My chat is working well when I publish it on a single server. But when I get publish it in **multiple** servers by docker swarm. I get this error.

*Unable to connect to the server with any of the available transports. WebSockets failed: Error: There was an error with the transport.*

By this error message, the app is just sometimes working normally. When I leave the page and return back it is not working again.

I am using ubuntu server. I both aligned the versions of signalR on server and client. They are both using 5.0.3. I don't have proxy server in front of the app and I m using load balancing feature of docker swarm.

**Configure Service**

```
var tokenKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"]));
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = tokenKey,
                    ValidateAudience = false, 
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
                opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                        {
                            if (path.StartsWithSegments("/chat")
                            || path.StartsWithSegments("/dialog"))
                            {
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

**Configure Void**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat", opt => { opt.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets; });     
            endpoints.MapHub<DialogHub>("/dialog", opt => { opt.Transports =  HttpTransportType.WebSockets; }); 

        });
```

Comment: are you using your app in azure? if not then i dont think its possible, because you need a service in front of those containers which redirects the messages appropriately

Comment: No mate i dont use azure. You think is it reason of the problem ? Which service should I use of Azure ? And can I just use that service and keep my app in another server or should I publish my all API services in azure ?

Comment: i think so, sadly i cant help you further, because after i learned that its not possible to use signalR outside of azure in a swarm i lost interest in it. You might want to add the azure tag to your question. Good Luck ;)

Comment: Thank you so much mate to spend your time and answer me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When scaling out SignalR to multiple servers, a shared data plane would be needed to manage distributed state, in addition to the network considerations.

As noted in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-5.0), Microsoft suggests either introducing a Redis backplane or delegating to their managed service, Azure SignalR.

> An app that uses SignalR needs to keep track of all its connections,
> which creates problems for a server farm. Add a server, and it gets
> new connections that the other servers don't know about.

Having used Azure SignalR, it's fairly straightforward to [integrate with an ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core) app. You then have offloaded all the overhead of managing connections from your app.

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend. I ve already started to read about it and will try something about it

Answer (score 0):

@Noah Stahl that's exactly what I was thinking. The signalR hubs started with both applications would be different unless the two applications share a 3rd service. My solution was a database and an angular front end shared between 2 apis with singlarR to communicate real time with the front end. This may not be the solution you're looking for but figured it's help someone looking.